# Plugin/etc. for users adding points to a map on your homepage

Tags: qgis

Is there a plugin for if you want to create a map where users (on your homepage) can enter point data?
It is a pretty simple thing, I assume. Just want to have a map on my homepage where any person can add points (maybe even lines) to my map, which is then gathered in a spreadsheet of some sort for me (readable by QGIS). They should be able to choose a category for their point. It's for a map where cyclists can report where they feel unsafe, lack of bike lane etc.

Comment: Which technology do you use for your online-map? Leaflet, Openlayers, something else?

Comment: I haven't even come to that part. So whichever works the best. :)

Comment: anyone out there with an answer?